# How is force.com platform different from wave platform

Tags: analytics, einstein-analytics

Salesforce is built on Force.com and we see that Analytics cloud is built on Wave Platform. What is the difference between these to platforms (force.com Vs Wave)

Answer (score 0):

In my (limited) experience, you can access Wave directly inside a Salesforce org. The biggest difference I've seen is that to use Wave you are likely going to need to do a bit of work with data formatted in JSON, where most strict Force.com platform Apps do not require JSON modifications to ensure they work correctly.  I'm sure others will have more experience, I have only played with it a little.  The other thing I have noticed is that the vast majority of Wave implementations are using an ETL tool, while again, Salesforce itself is not billed as an ETL tool nor does it require one out of the box.

Comment: work in JSON?  JSON is a data format, not a programming language

Comment: I realize that. I mean that you have to do a lot of data manipulation in JSON to get the data sets right. Much like you might need to do a lot of manipulation in Excel to get something right for import. Being familiar with the data format is just an additional skill not normally needed working with Apex/Visualforce/Lightning.

Comment: The real difference is the model of the two platforms.... its ETL vs ELT.  Take a look at this: https://www.ironsidegroup.com/2015/03/01/etl-vs-elt-whats-the-big-difference/